# update database table from c# through stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I need here to update my database table from c# code.
I have one bindingList in which i do some calculations which need to be updated in database . I have also stored procedure for update query. When i run mu app, number of rows in my database are updated with the record from last row. My question is why does not all rows updated, why just last row of table is updated in the place of all rows? Please help me here im stucked here two days.
Here is code

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare p inside the loop.  If you declare it outside the loop all p added to the list will have the same value

```
    foreach (var stavka in priemnicaStavki)
    {
        PriemStavka p = new PriemStavka();
        p.ArtKatBrMat = stavka.ArtKatBrMat;
```

also you are not using parm you do not need it in

```
public int EditPriemStavkaAllByKurs(PriemStavka entity)
```

Store procedure needs to be updated also.  You need a where clause to find the record to update not all of them.  I am assuming the first column is the primary key in the update list was the primary key.  You may need to modify the procedure slightly

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [citaj].[usp_EditPriemStavkaKurs2]  

@SlogID  int = null, @OdobrenieRBr  int = null, @ZaklucokBroj nvarchar(50) = null, @DokRBr  int = null, @DokumentBroj nvarchar(50) = null, @DokumentDatum datetime = null, @FakturaU5RBr  int = null, @ArtRBrMat  int = null, @ArtKatBrMat nvarchar(50) = null, @ArtNazivMat nvarchar(255) = null, @TarBr nvarchar(10) = null, @Kol char(50) = null, @EdMer nvarchar(16) = null, @EdMerCar nvarchar(3) = null, @Cena char(50) = null, @Valuta nvarchar(255) = null, @Vrednost char(50) = null, @Sirina char(50) = null, @M2 char(50) = null, @ZemjaPoteklo nvarchar(255) = null, @NaimRBr  int = null, @DavackiEdinica char(50) = null, @Davacki char(50) = null, @Korisnik  int = null, @Tezina char(50) = null, @SpecTez char(50) = null, @VrednostBruto char(50) = null, @ZaklucokBrojPrenos nvarchar(50) = null, @StatVred char(50) = null, @KoletiS nvarchar(50) = null, @KoletiBr char(50) = null, @TezinaBruto char(50) = null, @CarSt char(50) = null, @Carina char(50) = null, @Danok char(50) = null, @StavkaRBr  int = null

as

UPDATE PriemiSt SET   ZaklucokBroj = @ZaklucokBroj,  DokRBr = @DokRBr,  DokumentBroj = @DokumentBroj,  DokumentDatum = @DokumentDatum,  FakturaU5RBr = @FakturaU5RBr,  ArtRBrMat = @ArtRBrMat,  ArtKatBrMat = @ArtKatBrMat,  ArtNazivMat = @ArtNazivMat,  TarBr = @TarBr,  Kol = @Kol,  EdMer = @EdMer,  EdMerCar = @EdMerCar,  Cena = @Cena,  Valuta = @Valuta,  Vrednost = @Vrednost,  Sirina = @Sirina,  M2 = @M2,  ZemjaPoteklo = @ZemjaPoteklo,  NaimRBr = @NaimRBr,  DavackiEdinica = @DavackiEdinica,  Davacki = @Davacki,  Korisnik = @Korisnik,  Tezina = @Tezina,  SpecTez = @SpecTez,  VrednostBruto = @VrednostBruto,  ZaklucokBrojPrenos = @ZaklucokBrojPrenos,  StatVred = @StatVred,  KoletiS = @KoletiS,  KoletiBr = @KoletiBr,  TezinaBruto = @TezinaBruto,  CarSt = @CarSt,  Carina = @Carina,  Danok = @Danok,  StavkaRBr = @StavkaRBr

where OdobrenieRBr = @OdobrenieRBr
```

Comment: how without parametar this   p.ArtKatBrMat = stavka.ArtKatBrMat; to give in BL.BL.EditPriemStavkaAllByKurs(p); how to execute without parametar, in this way all records are 0

Comment: and in debug mode, i see that my procedure in dall class fro one record return all records, in part of one she gets to update all rows

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SlogID", entity.SlogID); will create a sqlparameter for you and add it to the command

Comment: doesnt working, i;ve tried on each way

Comment: procedure is problem, but i dont know what is wrong inside

Comment: added a where clause to the store procedure in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Ken Tucker, i solve my problem.